What is the best pattern for "edit screen" (The creation is via progress steps)
I am working on a flow of creating a complex entity. The creation process consists of 3 steps. Each of them has a lengthy form.
Now I need to also allow editing of this entity after creation. Should I follow with the process design pattern or may be use vertical tabs instead (so it will remove the element of dependency)?
Another thing important to mention is that the entity may be in Draft status 
Note: One thought I had is that the edit screen will have vertical tabs instead of steps.

There are a few best practices regarding the creation flow:

For complex multi-step processes, it's useful to add another step at the end, showing a static summary of all answers in order to allow users to verify them.

For complex forms, it's useful to add a progress bar that shows how much of the form is completed. You could also add numbers for each form step, representing completed fields vs total fields (like 3/4 answers), or be percentages (like 75% done).

For multiple steps, it's also useful to give them a title, so that users know the meaning of each step. That also helps when navigating between steps.



Regarding editing a draft or a completed form, there are a few situations:

If there is a clear dependency between steps (like dependent fields), then your only option is to show the exact same UI for both creation and editing.

If there is no dependency and you don't have any summary view, then you can either show steps or tabs, as long as users can jump between them. It's also important to mark which steps/tabs have fields that need to be completed. From a development point of view, showing steps for both creation and editing is easier, since it's less to implement and also avoids possible misunderstandings.

If there is no dependency and your form has a summary view, then you can show only the summary view in editing mode and use in-place editing pattern for updating each field (basically adding a button that transforms the static text into a form field, and then a save button to apply the changes). This allows users to easily scan the summary and make quick changes where needed. You could also transform the whole summary into a single long form, if it's easier to implement.



Personally, I find that option 3 (or a variation of it) to be the most user friendly, since you also need to somehow display the entity after creating it.
